# SQL: selecting one of multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
Name   Number 
--------------
A        1 
A       Null 
A        2
B       Null 
B       Null
```

Output I want is

```
Name.    Number 
B.        Null
```

I just want records that just have null value

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use grouping and a having clause

```
select Name, max(Number) as Number
from Table
group by Name
having max(Number) is null
```